# Compute the number of epoch from iteration in training data set?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm trying to solve a DeepLearning PB in which I took 8000 input data points in the training set and a batch size of 10 and the number of epochs is 100, so per epoch my iterations come to look like 5359/5359 at every epoch.

What is the relation between

- batch size,
- epoch,
- the total number of iterations,
- number of input features and
- the number of passes in the case deep learning model training?

Comment: I reformatted your question. Hope that you like the improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the reformate my question but can you pls explain them also?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I do not know enough about that topic.